# Pass values in an array as select form

Tags: php, sql

I have this part here which generates me an array:

```
$ids_sektor = explode("/",$row['sektori']);
```

What i need is to echo all those values inside a select option...
The html for my selectbox is:

```
 <select id="sektori_pergjegjes" name="sektori_pergjegjes">
                <option value="A">A</option>
                <option value="B">B</option>
                <option value="C">C</option>
                <option value="D">D</option>
                <option value="E">E</option>
</select>
```

I tried foreach but no success, i guess i'm doing something wrong, of cours ei am, some help please.

Comment: Show the value of `$row['sektori']` and your `foreach` try.

Comment: hi, pls post an examlpe of how `$row['sektori']`looks like

Comment: Yes so, there are values like :A/B/C/D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work as follows:

```
   $row['sektori'] = "12/34/56";
   $ids_sektor = explode("/", $row['sektori'];

   foreach ($ids_sektor as $id) {
       echo "<option>$id</option>\n";
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understood the question well, but it should be done like that:

```
<select id="sektori_pergjegjes" name="sektori_pergjegjes">
<?php
    foreach($ids_sektor as $item)
    {
        $id = htmlspecialchars(item);
        echo('<option value="' . $id . '">' . $id . '</option>');
    }
?>
</select>
```

You may skip `htmlspecialchars()` when you're 100% sure there will be just `A/B/C/D/E` in your array.

Comment: ASP-style short tags make me cry. Also, HTML escape~